# .NET MVC 3 How to cycle modelstate errors and force ModelState.Valid or disable specific errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, validation, action-filter

I am using MVC 3 + unobstrusive validation.

For some field I am using remote validation too; inside remote validation, I do some checks whose can return errors or **just warnings** (I would like to take advantage of ajax validation just to give warnings too, not just blocking errors).
I distinct the warnings by the validation errors with the "Info" prefix inside de description text.

**So, does exist a way to cycle all validation errors, maintaining just warnings displayed and set errors off according the displayed text?**

**I was thinking of using an ActionFilterAttribute, or to force the ModelState.Valid = true after cycling and checking all the validation errors...**

Here's an extract of my remote validation routine, with a WarningCheck attribute:

```
   [WarningCheck]
   public JsonResult CheckMyField(string myfield) 
    {

        //....some check...if ok I do `return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`
        //...if just a warning, I do the follow...

        string warn = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            "Info: some info....");
        ModelState.AddModelError(TicketHD, esiste);
        return Json(warn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public class WarningCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
      public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
       {  
             //.... here I'd like to cycle my warnings and if possible maintaining just the text display and set errors off...is it possible?
       }
     }
```

**EDIT (how to disable client side validation for specific warnings)**

Following @CDSmith (@Alfalfastrange) suggestions for server side, I succeed to disable the client side validation too, when a specific text is contained inside each validation error. In particular, my needs were to disable both client & server side validation error just when the errors contained "Info:" text. 
Here's the code I am using for client side behaviour:

```
       .... 
                    $("#ticketfrm").submit();
                    var isvalid = true;
                    var errmark = $("#ticketfrm .field-validation-error span"); 
                    $(errmark).each(function () {
                        var tst = $(this).text();
                        if (!(tst.indexOf("Info") != -1))
                            isvalid = false; //if the val error is not a warn, the it must be a real error!
                        });

                    if (isvalid) {
                        var form = $('#ticketfrm').get(0); //because I'm inside a jquery dialog
                         $.removeData(form, 'validator'); 
                        jQuery('#ticketfrm').unbind('submit').submit();
                    }

                    $("#ticketfrm").submit();   
                }
            .....
```

I hope this may help many people...I worked many hours to get this working! I do not think it must be the more elegant solution, but IT WORKS! :)
While for server side validation, please read the marked solution.

If you find this useful, please mark it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question as well as you're explaining but what I hear you saying is you need a way of looping thru the ModelState errors and then maintaining the text values of the errors but not show them as errors?? Is that what you are saying?

Well for starters, ModelState is nothing more than a DictionaryList which you can iterate through with no problem.

Something like this can do that:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        // do cool stuff with model data
    }
    var errorMessages = GetModelStateErrors(ModelState);
    foreach (var errorMessage in errors) {
        // do whatever you want with the error message string here
    }
}
```

ModelError contains an ErrorMessage property and Exception property

```
internal static List<string> GetModelStateErrors(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>> modelStateDictionary) {
    var errors = new List<ModelError>();
    errors = modelStateDictionary.SelectMany(item => item.Value.Errors).ToList();
}
```

Not sure if this helps or not but if it points you in the right direction then cool :-)

**Update**

Ok here is what I came up with and it works for me with my test app.

First let me lay out what I have so you can copy and replicate

**Here's my model**

```
public class EmployeeViewModel {

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**Here's a simple view that uses this model**

```
@model TestApp.Models.EmployeeViewModel

<h2>Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>EmployeeViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

**Here's the controller and actions that I used**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestApp.Models;

namespace TestApp.Controllers {

    public class HomeController : Controller {

        public ActionResult Index() {
            return RedirectToAction("Test");
        }

        public ActionResult Test() {
            var model = new EmployeeViewModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(EmployeeViewModel model) {
            // Force an error on this property - THIS should be the only real error that gets returned back to the view
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error on First Name");

            if(model.EmailAddress == null) // Add an INFO message
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email Address Info");
            if (model.Username == null) // Add another INFO message
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username Info");

            // Get the Real error off the ModelState
            var errors = GetRealErrors(ModelState);

            // clear out anything that the ModelState currently has in it's Errors collection
            foreach (var modelValue in ModelState.Values) {
                modelValue.Errors.Clear();
            }
            // Add the real errors back on to the ModelState
            foreach (var realError in errors) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", realError.ErrorMessage);
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        private IEnumerable<ModelError> GetRealErrors(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>> modelStateDictionary) {
            var errorMessages = new List<ModelError>() ;
            foreach (var keyValuePair in modelStateDictionary) {
                if (keyValuePair.Value.Errors.Count > 0) {
                    foreach (var error in keyValuePair.Value.Errors) {
                        if (!error.ErrorMessage.Contains("Info")) {
                            errorMessages.Add(error);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return errorMessages;
        }
    }
}
```

**You can write GetRealErrors as LINQ instead if you prefer:**

```
private IEnumerable<ModelError> GetRealErrors(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>> modelStateDictionary) {
    var errorMessages = new List<ModelError>() ;
    foreach (var keyValuePair in modelStateDictionary.Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Errors.Count > 0)) {
        errorMessages.AddRange(keyValuePair.Value.Errors.Where(error => !error.ErrorMessage.Contains("Info")));
    }
    return errorMessages;
}
```

I hope that gives you what you were looking for, it works the way I think I understand that you wanted. Let me know

Comment: THX @CD Smith. You're right. I'd like to loop "thru the ModelState errors and then maintaining the text values of the errors but not show them as errors"...but I'd like to do it just for some errors. In particular, I'd like to maintaing ALL errors, EXCEPT those with the string "Info" inside the text...is it possible?
Could you make a more specific answer, on the basis of my details, please? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh ok, Yes I see what you mean now, give me a few mins, I'll update the answer

Comment: I updated my answer, have a look at that and see what you think

Comment: Thank you very much @CD Smith.You made me realize I should intercept POST action 4ex.Your solution seems works fine if you add your own model errors during post action..unfortunately I did not succeed to get it work:in my case,I am using `RemoteValidation` and other attributes like `Required` one directly in my model.You can test with your model too,if you do not fill `FirstName` field, for example...**What happens if someone omits to write inside a required field,4 ex?I am trying to post data, but it's inhibited due the client side validation errors**.Do you have a final solution,please?

Comment: Typically in a web app that's what you want, you want client side validation and also the same kind of validation on the server at Post in case someone circumvents the browser and posts data of their own with some hacker tool.So There's not much choice left. You can create your own client side custom validation or turn off client side jquery validation.

Comment: You're right @CD Smith. In fact I want to mantain both client and server side validation. Does not exist a way to intercept the client side validation on HttpGet method and then apply your solution before the HttpPost is fired?

Comment: You can create custom jquery validation but I'm unfamiliar with what it takes to do that. I've only done some hacky manual javascript validation such as when a submit button is clicked, I manually check the fields I want to check and then show some hidden divs with the error text and cancel the submit. That's not a very clean solution tho for something like what you are looking for, you need something that is more aspect oriented since you're going to use it globally

Comment: THX CD Smith...I think that with your hints the solution is near...I'd like to intercept the first validation result. I think that the submit is inhibited via jquery or some javascript. If I could hack the javascript too and enable the submit button when there are no real errors, but just warnings, then I could use your code for server side validation...

Comment: Yes the submit, if there are any client validation errors, is inhibited. You can intercept with something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593110/submit-mvc3-form-that-uses-data-annotations-with-div-jquery/10593139#10593139

Comment: THX! Really interesting...so I should cycle all validation errors with jquery...something similar what you did on server side, right? Then, if there is any "blocking" error, I should re-enable the submit button...the server side code should do the other...right?
I will try to cycle the validation errors text inside the form validation...Could you help me please?

Comment: i've been looking for a way to loop thru client side errors but there's no object to loop thru. Basically after you click the submit the client side validation runs (this is jquery code running which you would have to write your own version of jquery to intercept the validation)

Comment: <input class="LogInAreaUsernameTextField" data-val="true" data-val-length="Username must be at least 6 and no more than 30 characters" data-val-length-max="30" data-val-length-min="6" data-val-regex="Username can only be alphanumeric, no special characters allowed" data-val-regex-pattern="^[\w\s]+$" data-val-required="The Username field is required." id="logInArea_Username" name="Username" type="text" value="">------------------------------ this is what a textbox looks like with validation attributes...

Comment: <input class="TextField_220 input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-email="Please enter a valid email address" data-val-required="The Email Address field is required." id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" type="text" value="">-----------------this is a field that just failed validation. You might be able to use jquery like so: if($(this).isvalid()) {...} else { // use jquery to find all the input elements that have class of "input-validation-error" and then check each data-val-X message for "Error" or "Info"

Comment: Hi @CD Smith. Thank you for your help and your interest. I almost suceed to cycle and override client side validation too. I'll put client side solution inside the question, to complete the answer for other people and I'll mark your one as solution for server side.Cu soon. THX!

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get it where you wanted it. I'm sure many others would definitely be interested in seeing the finished code

Comment: THX so much! I've just updated with client side solution and marked your one as solution. Merging your and mine solutions, it works like a charm! :)))

Comment: Very nice!! glad that worked out! and I'm sure you learned a lot in the process :-)

Comment: Thanks @CD Smith for your answer, I was looking for a way to iterate through the ModelState and your answer saved me!