# Submit MVC3 form that uses Data Annotations with div/jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, submit, data-annotations

So, I have a form on the page that I was using an input type="submit" to register users.  After adding Data Annotations, some custom, some built-in, I wanted to customize the look of the input submit button only to find out that I cannot get it to match the other buttons on the page which are just divs/links.  So, I would like to make it a div that uses jquery to submit the form and call of the data annotation's built-in and customized jquery before submitting.  I tried this:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Register", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "registerForm" }))
  {`
  < div id="registerSubmit" class="divSubmit">
        < a>Register< / a>
    < / div>`}`

`$("#registerSubmit").onclick(function () {
        $("#registerForm").submit();
    });`

But, that is not working for me.  Is there a way to submit and call the DA code correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use to achieve the very same thing

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var submitButton = document.getElementById("registerSubmit");

    submitButton.onclick = function (event) {
        // do cool stuff before submit like validation or confirmations, whatever
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            // more cool stuff
            $("#registerForm").submit();
        }
        return false;
    };
});
```

Comment: As simple as valid() is, it was exactly what I needed.  Thank you!  To use all jquery, I did: 

$("#registerSubmit").click(function () {
        if ($("#registerForm").valid()) {
            $("#registerForm").submit();
        }
    });